# Unable to auto click/trigger on button of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Here, Iframe is auto generated by js script. Now i want to click by trigger a button but i unable. Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amrj477a/).

I have tried all possible way from my side but  unable to get solution.

Code:-

```
$(function(){ 
   $(window).load(function(){   

   alert($("iframe.tableauViz").contents().find('#primary-auth').html());


   $("iframe.tableauViz").contents().find('#primary-auth').click(function(){
    alert('clicked'); 
   });

 });

})
```

Comment: So you don't get to see the alert? Is the iframe on your domain? Any errors in your console?

Comment: No, iframe src is not on our domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you write function on you page for element on `<iframe>` it will not work. You can't apply function on anything in `<iframe>`.

But yes if `<iframe>` is on you domain and you have access to if write function on that page which you are calling in `<iframe>` of different page.

> Elements in iframe are not accessible from function on different page.

Comment: thanks for reply @GauravAggarwal, i just click a button which generate in my page. Is this not possible?

Comment: not in `<iframe>` if you have access to iframe page use function on that page it will automatically be working on your new page